# How do I set the visual state of a textbox?

Tags: c#, windows, visualstatemanager

1.I cant set the visual state of my textbox, with my c# code the text   shows   up but the animation does not run, any ideas, or corrections on my c# code would be helpful for me to understand

below is my xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Name="instructions_text2" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Press Start and drag!"  Foreground="#FFCB1717" FontSize="30" FontFamily="AR DELANEY"  />
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CustomGroups">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Blue">
                            <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"  >
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
                                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

c# code:

```
        TextBox instructions = new TextBox();
        instructions.Template = Resources["instructions_text2"] as ControlTemplate;
          instructions.Width = playArea.ActualWidth;
          instructions.Height = playArea.ActualHeight;
          VisualStateManager.GoToState(instructions, "Blue", true);
        playArea.Children.Add(instructions);
```

Comment: What result do you expect? At the moment it appears that the TextBox will come visible at 0.2 seconds but it will be totally transparent. Then by 1 second it will be fully opaque but by 2 seconds it will be totally transparent again.

Comment: yes, basically the text should appear and disappear, but for some reason the animation is not working, maybe it has to do with the control template or the c# code, because the animation is correct from what I understand

Comment: It works if you a) add `x:Key="Test"` to the template and b) define the TextBox in XAML. I can't seem to get it to work if I define the text box in the code behind.

Comment: I have to make it work with the c# code behind

Comment: If I check the return result from `GoToState` it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change the visual state of the TextBox before it's ready. In fact you are trying to change the state before it's been added to the visual tree.

Change your code to be:

```
    TextBox instructions = new TextBox();
    instructions.Template = Resources["instructions_text2"] as ControlTemplate;
    instructions.Width = playArea.ActualWidth;
    instructions.Height = playArea.ActualHeight;
    instructions.Loaded += Instructions_Loaded;
    playArea.Children.Add(instructions);
```

Then in the Loaded handler you can go to the state you want.

```
    private void Instructions_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = VisualStateManager.GoToState(sender as FrameworkElement, "Blue", true);
    }
```

NOTE: There are two versions of VisualStateManager. The one I used is in the namespace `System.Windows` and it's `GoToState` takes a `FrameworkElement` as the first argument - this is the one used by traditional desktop applications. There's also a VisualStateManager in `Windows.UI.Xaml` that takes a `Control` as the first argument - this is the one used by new Windows App programs.

As `TextBox` is a type of control:

```
    private void Instructions_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = VisualStateManager.GoToState(sender as Control, "Blue", true);
    }
```

should work.

Also the ControlTemplate needs a Key, not a Name *:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="instructions_text2" TargetType="TextBox">
```

The resources dictionary uses the Key value as it's key, so at the moment you're not finding the resource at all so `instructions.Template` is null.

* *this may only be true for desktop applications*

Comment: Error: cannot convert from 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control'  , changed it to  var result = VisualStateManager.GoToState(sender as ContentControl, "Blue", true);  comes up with NullReference exception

Comment: @topoall - where do you get this error? I had this code working in VS2015.

Comment: I have VS 2015 community , [error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/icDjb.png) [error2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WCVGN.png)

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? I can't see why that's not working.

Comment: I tried 4.5.1 and 4.6.1 same problem, it must be something else, not the .net framework

Comment: You need to use the **Key** to find the resource not the **Name**,.

Comment: thank you for your help so far, is it possible to elaborate on that?, I changed the  xaml ControlTemplate to <ControlTemplate x:Key="instructions_text2" TargetType="TextBox"> , but i am still in a mesh:(

Comment: It looks like that's not the source of the problem. It appears there are two versions of `VisualStateManager` whose `GoToState` methods have different parameter profiles. One is for traditional desktop apps (which is the one I used) the other is for new style applications (which is the one you are using) - hence the confusion. I think I've got it sorted now.

Comment: we are definitely getting close, theres no null reference anymore, but two possible problems occur: either the text appears but the animation doesn't work or An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurs in xxxxxxx.Windows.exe but was not handled in user code

WinRT information: Animation target not specified.

Additional information: No installed components were detected